# Could this garage door's bowing be caused by someone falling into it?

Tags: structural-engineering, structures, structural-analysis

The tension spring broke on our garage door causing it to fall. Afterward, the garage looked as it does in the pictures below. The most straightforward explanation to me is that the impact of the fall caused the door to bend between the bottom two panels causing the damage seen. Assuming a person falling into the door could have caused the damage, it's also a slight possibility that a guest could have fallen back into it while playing ping pong and we didn't notice the bending until after the door fell.

**Given the pictures, how likely is it that that type of bowing could be caused by someone/something impacting the garage door?** The damage seems like exactly what I'd expect from the several hundred pound door falling on itself and if that weren't the case, it really doesn't seem likely that, if it could withstand that impact without damage, then someone falling into it would be able to contort it to that extent. Also given that it's bowing across the entire width and not bent around a localized area make it seem even less plausible that it could have some lateral impact on it. Then again, I don't know anything about the structural integrity of garage doors and if they're much better at withstanding a drop than something hitting it from the side.

[image: garage door bowing]

More images can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aovHR.jpg)

Comment: I understand what you are asking, but don't understand why you are asking. I'm assuming that you are having a disagreement with someone about the damage. A random group of people on the internet isn't going to help persuade someone.

Comment: @hazzey, Yeah, it's a dispute with our landlord. I'm not asking in hopes that the answer would prove my position, just trying to get an idea of how reasonable the alternate explanation is

Comment: If something hit then there can be some residue left on door. If the vehicle backed in then there will be paint left depending on impact. I don't think you will find the answer here in this forum.

Comment: -1 for asking a question, but arguing or leading to a particular answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Too low to be a human, maybe a car did it

After looking at the other pictures, the bulge seems to be too low to have been done by a human.  If someone had fallen into the door from a fall (pingpong), I'd expect the bulge to be higher on the door since if the person was most of the way fallen over, the force of their fall would be going down, not out as we see in the picture.  Also, the bowing would be more pointed because humans aren't that wide, so the impact would be more focused in a small area.

The bump look like it's at the right height and the right width to be a car impact. From the picture where the SUV is visible, it's easy to draw a horizontal line from the bumper to the bulge. You can see that there's no significant bowing on any of the other panels so the impact was delivered only at that height.

Given that this bulge was only discovered after the spring broke, it may have been there for years.  A human is unlikely to have done that damage.

Comment: If the door was open and a vehicle was partly backed out of the garage when the spring failed, the door may have hit the vehicle as it swung down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your picture is definitive one way or the other.  If there are some scrape marks, transferred paint, etc at the center of the bow, then it would make it more likely something bumped into the door.  Since there don't appear to be any, either scenario is plausible.